# In python read from one specific word in a file to another specificword in a file multiple times

Tags: python, file

Okay, so. Bit of an annoying one this. I have a file with multiple 'sections' in it. The file *may* like this:

```
"""
Begin presentation. Welcome the new guest. Do this, do that

[+] Start group 1
+derrek
+bob
+james
+harry

[+] Start group 2
+Will
+Paul
+Mark
+Eric

Hello and welcome to this years presentation of the "New Show" feature me your host Troy Mcleur. Something blah blah blah
"""
```

So, my question is, is it possible to write some Python to parse both the first and second groups of names, so you only print them? So, the output would only be:

```
[+] Start group 1
derrek
bob
james
harry

[+] Start group 2
Will
Paul
Mark
Eric
```

At the moment, the code I currently have is this:

```
for line in file:
     if 'Start Group' in line:
         print line
             break
 for line in file:
     if 'Start Group' in line:
         break
     print line
```

This only prints Group 1 though, it wont print the next group. Also, occasionally some files may have between 2 and 9 groups, so I'd need it to iterate through and find all the instances of Group, and print all the names within them.

Comment: Is it possible for you to convert your .txt files to `xml` for example? Then you could easily parse them using `lxml` library.

Comment: It is possible, but I was hoping for an easier example than having to convert filetypes or writing to new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
from __future__ import print_function

show = False
for line in fobj:
    if line.strip().startswith('[+]'):
        print()
        show = True
    elif not line.strip():
        show = False
    if show:
        print(line, end='')
```

Output:

```
[+] Start group 1
+derrek
+bob
+james
+harry

[+] Start group 2
+Will
+Paul
+Mark
+Eric
```

Comment: Why not just print `line.strip()` instead of worrying about the future `print()` function?

Comment: There are different ways to do it. I like the one from the future. You should use Python 3 anyway. ;) I do.

Comment: Hi Mike, this solution worked really well. Thanks for the help.